# can you tell me what this regular expression means?

Tags: php, regex

im new to regular expressions and would like to decipher this.

```
return preg_replace("/[<>]/", '_', $string);
```

thanks!!

Comment: It means, replace `the sad robot waving with his arms` with `an indifferent face` - that's what it means.

Comment: Sad robot?! It looks like two sparrows french-kissing to me.

Comment: @hollsk nope, that's just your dirty fantasy playing tricks on ya ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means "replace each `<` or `>` inside the string `$string` with an underscore, then return the result".

The slashes (`/`) delimit the regular expression. You can use other characters instead (`preg_replace("#[<>]#", '_', $string);` would work just as well and makes sense if your regex contains a slash itself).

`[]` brackets denote a character class. They mean essentially "one character of those contained within the class", so `[<>]` means "either a `<` or a `>`".

You can also negate a character class by starting it with a `^`: `[^<>]` means "any character except `<` or `>`.

Comment: Beat me by 30 seconds. Just glad my answer was right. :P

Comment: thanks that's very helpful, the only thing i dont get is whats the point of using the / at the start and end of the argument, (or # as you show in the example) , would the function not work by simply using "[<>]" 

thanks!

Comment: It wouldn't work since PHP requires the use of regex delimiters. I can't tell you why though - other languages have implemented this differently. Python or .NET use strings (without additional delimiters), Ruby has regexes as first-class objects so they need their own delimiter (`/`). In JavaScript you can choose to build a regex using a string (`"..."`) or a regex object (`/.../`). Why you need both in PHP - no idea.

Comment: ok great, thanks for the help you are very knowledgable

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is replacing either the greater than or the less than sign with an underscore. But I am a little rusty in regex